# Extract/pull data based on 2 criteria to column

Tags: excel-2010, lookup-tables

I am seeking an advice related to Microsoft excel 2010,

My tables:

[image]

In Table_3,

- To populate column [AMOUNT] with values from Table_2 which match Employees Names for a selected month;
- To populate the columns [SNO], [EMPLOYEE NAME], [ACC NO.] & [BANK] with values from Table_1 which match a selected option "Internet Banking" in column [PAYMENT METHOD] of Table_1 and bank name selected in Table_3.

(Noted that column [EMPLOYEE NAME] of Table_2 values are referenced from column [EMPLOYEE NAME] of Table_1)

I have tried several formulas related to Index&Match however the columns are being populated with the first match only,

I am trying to automate the process as much as possible. I have spent several days in learning excel however unfortunately I was not successful

What is the best approach to achieve this that is compatible with Office 2010?

Comment: Please include all the necessary info in your question, not 3rd party sites like google drive.

Comment: As @JamesZ said - please add any images to the post (should be able to just paste them in).  Google drive is blocked, so no idea what you're showing.

Comment: My apologies for the inconvenience, I have edited the post and added the photo for the mentioned tables; Many thanks in advance.